# Parse file and replace tags with another file content

Tags: bash

Given files:

```
index.html
incl/body.html (which contains text "<h1>Title</h1>")
```

I want a script that "compiles" html files (eg index.html) from:

```html
<html>
<body>
<custom:include "incl/body.html" />
</body>
</html>
```

to

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

by copying the content of incl/body.html and overwriting the include tag.

I've made this script so far:

```bash
for f in build/*.html;
do
    echo Compiling file $f;
    <what to write here>
done
rm -r incl <as this folder is not needed after compilation)
```

how do I implement this logic?

*Edit: The question is a simplified extract from a build and deploy process where static html files are generated. I am aware of Server side includes in various languages, but I need this implemented in bash.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that this does not parse HTML and relies on the include command to look exactly like in your example (i.e. everything in one line, no extra spaces etc.)

```bash
while read l; do 
    if grep -qE '<custom:include "[^"]+" />' <<< "$l" ; then
        cat "$(sed -r 's#<custom:include "([^"]+)" />#\1#'  <<< "$l")"
    else
        echo "$l"
    fi
done  < input_file
```

I would usually recommend using a real template engine for this.

Comment: Thanks, but that just prints out the output, whereas I want the overwrite the original html file

Comment: Just redirect it into a temporary file and overwrite your original file afterwards (e.g. `... < "$f" > "${f}.tmp" ; mv "${f}.tmp" "$f"`

Comment: Accepted your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a few templating languages, for example `php`:

You write your `index.html` like this:

```php
<html>
<body>
<?php require "incl/body.html"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you run:

```bash
php index.html
```

That'll output:

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is a simplified extract from a build and deploy process where static html files are generated. Server side includes is not a solution for my need unfortunately.

Comment: @KelvinWayne You're a little mistaken here; you would run `php` from the command-line for generating static HTML, that's not a server-side include at all. `php file.txt` is exactly equivalent to `cat file.txt` when there's no `<?php ... ?>` tag in the file. If you want to keep a syntax like `<custom include="incl/body.html" />` then you should add the `XML` `XPath` `XQuery` tags to your question

Comment: Right, I understand what you are saying. This could be an alternative solution.